# Using .gitignore to only include specific directories and their subdirectories

Tags: wordpress, git

I am using a Git repo for my Wordpress starter kit with all my plugins and themes when starting a project.

Currently I have to delete all files I don't want by hand and I would like to automate this with .gitignore.

What need to be included:

`/wp-content/themes/ and all the subdirectories in here
/wp-content/plugins/ and all the subdirectories in here`

My question is: how can I do this using .gitignore on a complete Wordpress install?

I have found similar questions on Stackoverflow, but I didn't find any answers that include all subdirectories.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
!wp-content/themes/
!wp-content/plugins/
```

Keep in mind the trailing slash is important.